# Terraform remote state chicken and egg

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

In order to store state remotely terraform has a config block that allows you point to a cloud resource. [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/terraform/store-state-in-azure-storage) article shows how to do it in Azure.

In a nutshell, it instructs the reader to use some AZ powershell commands to provision the resources.

Isn't the idea of Terraform to do the opposite of manual creation of resources? If this is true, what is a better way to do this? If its not, and I've misunderstood something, please clarify what it is that I missed.

Background: working on a greenfield application with nothing provisioned other than a git repo to store the tf files. Attempting to provision an azure static web site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terraform scaffold for Azure:

https://github.com/whiteducksoftware/terraform-scaffold-for-azure

Answer (score 3):

Its normal. To use a [remote backed on azurem](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/settings/backends/azurerm.html) you need to have [Azure Blob container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-introduction). So it must exist first, before you can use it for a remote backed.

You don't have to use any powershell commands to create the container. Use other TF code, or Azure console, SDK or whatever you want to create it.

Comment: so basically run a script and save it to git? can you elaborate on what you mean by other TF code? Are you aware of any docs/posts from TF about how basically bootstrapping TF on the cloud requires at least some manual scripting to create the storage container and related resources (like a resource group)

Also the PS was just an example of manual scripting which is what the whole point of what IoC and TF is trying to get rid of from what I've read so far.

Comment: @ton.yeung If you run your code in CI/CD pipeline, you can setup a step that checks for existence of the container for the backend, and creates it if needed. You can do this using separate TF code only for creation of the container. Once it exists, regular TF deployments are executed.

Comment: terraform scaffold for azure = https://github.com/whiteducksoftware/terraform-scaffold-for-azure

Comment: @PhilipWelz can you make your comment an answer?

Comment: @Marcin thanks for the elaboration. Can you edit your answer to include the new information?